# Is there any known result about the "average period" of a complicated oscillating function?

Tags: fourier-transform, frequency, oscillators, signal-processing

Say we have some frequency spectrum, $f(\omega)$, where

$$
          f(t) = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\infty}^\infty d\omega \; f(\omega)e^{-i\omega t},
$$

and we know that $f(t)$ is some sort of oscillating function. If it helps, we can specify that $f(\omega)$ is smooth and has a single peak. Is there some sort of characterisation of the average distance between points where $f(t)$, or its real component, equals zero? I.e. some sort of "average/expected" period of oscillation?

Intuitively, one would expect it to be around the peak or average frequency in the spectrum, but I can't find any kind of precise result along these lines.

Comment: What do you mean in technical terms by "some sort of oscillating function"? An actual periodic function would have *discrete* Fourier spectrum.

Comment: I mean that you can expect it go to zero regularly, though not necessarily in an especially regular manner. The physical context I have here is some sort of complicated, partially-coherent, broad-spectrum light source.

Comment: I suppose I mean that over a very large distance, the response will have crossed zero many times.

Answer (score 0):

As an intro, you could do worse than the wiki page. Just don't let that be your only reference. Get yourself a good textbook on the subject. Even an intro text and a more advanced text if you are looking to really "study up."

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform

Usually you want to use a different symbol for the time-based function and the frequency-based function.  Say $f(t)$ and $F(\omega)$ or some such.

If the frequency spectrum is peaked around a single frequency, it means the time-based function has a strong component of that frequency. So, for example, if there was a single main frequency component with some noise, or some signal imposed on the main carrier, you could get something like that. There are other situations that will give you something like that. Without more info it is difficult to say more.

Comment: Yeah thanks I know what a Fourier Transform is. To be less abstract, the specific physical context I'm looking at is a black-body spectrum, which is certainly peaked at a value, but with quite a broad distribution. If you "zoomed in" on a microscopic portion of a black-body field, you would get some sort of chaotic, random field shape. I am wondering if there's a way of characterising, in particular, the average size of the gap between the zeros of this field shape.

Comment: @J_B_Phys  One might ask why you think the shape of the black body spectrum arises from anything other than the physics of black bodies.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't follow?

Comment: I have a (power) spectrum for the black body. That's given by physics, obviously. Given that spectrum, I want to know the average distance between zeros of the time-response. Where am I bringing in non-physical sources for the black-body spectrum?